# Do Pokerstars "juice" flops to make things more exciting?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-stars

I have been reading up on how to improve my play in Texas Hold'em and feel that my play has improved quite a bit.

However, my results for play money at Pokerstars do not seem to be very good.  Is this because Pokerstars "juices" the flops to make it more exciting?  Thanks.

Comment: If you search for discussions of whether sites are rigged on poker.se i expect youll find that there is a lot of data that supports the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Pokerstars has a very legit random number generator. Making flops more juicy to create bigger pots and thus more rake would be really stupid since they have a reputation to keep up. Big pokersites would never have a rigged deck.

The reason you are still losing could be because of two reasons.

- You are just unlucky. Your sample size simply is not big enough. Though possible, this is usually not the case.
- Poker is a difficult game. Reading one book might not be enough material. Read more, watch more, study more.

Comment: Saying big poker sites would never have a rigged a deck is just plain wrong. They say this about big licensed casinos and big companies in general and sooner or later the statement is proved wrong. They are not always honest people, think Fulltilt poker and Enron. However, your bullet points are spot on.

Comment: @jon as soon as the the company's reputation is gone, so are its customers. Pokerstars is making a ton of money, there really is no reason for them to rig their site and make a tiny little bit of extra cash for a chance to lose it all. Risk reward doesn't check out. Big poker companies would never rig their deck. I did a quick search and the issue you are talking about was not about rigged card decks but about bank and wire fraud.

Comment: Never say never. :)

Comment: Also keep in mind that all these flops are tracked by millions of people everyday by their pokertracker programs. If pokerstars even tried to deviate from the mathematically expected, sooner or later it would have been spotted. They have much easier and more clever ways to spice things up (roulette features, random prizes, VPIPs, Loyalty bonuses and other marketing tricks).